# get source codes for certain version of Nuget.Core?

Tags: c#, github, nuget

Is it possible to get source codes for certain version of `Nuget.Core`?

Version I would like to get source codes for:

```
Assembly: NuGet.Core, Version=1.6.30117.9648
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version is tagged in the [NuGet GitHub repository](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/).

The nearest tag I can see is for [1.6.1](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/tree/Release-1.6.1) which looks like it is not exactly the same as NuGet.Core, Version=1.6.30117.9648 since NuGet 1.6 was released on December 13, 2011, and the Release-1.6.1 tag has commits after that date.

Comment: Ohh yes I overlooked the tab ```Tags```. Thank you!